# Is it possible to run command of cmd using php?

Tags: php, cmd

Is it possible to run cmd command using php? i.e: I can see ip configuration as follows:
step1: open cmd
step2: run ipconfig/all

If I want to do this using php as like below what should I do:
I will input ipconfig/all in a text field then click a button named 'RUN' then I will get ip configuration as like as cmd command results.

Comment: [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: I'm going to have fun putting other input in that text field

Comment: See http://php.net for documentation. Usually the best place to start.

Comment: You could also issue a command that emails yourself the passwd file and all of your source code and databases. That would be convenient.

Comment: Why would you want to run cmd on the server?

Answer (score 0):

try `exec` and `shell_exec`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

before that, make sure you have enough privilege to run it.

Comment: Add the shorthand backtick version too ;)